# How to merge node.js and html?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I have an html file (home.html) and a node.js file (app.js).I used mysql also.What i have now is the app.js that is the server side that looks like this:

```
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require("express"),
    mysql = require('mysql');
    path = require("path");

    var app = express();
    var http = require('http');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({host : '127.0.0.1',user : 'root', password : '',database: "medical"
});

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
}); 


 app.get('/getallusers/:email', function (req, res) {
   connection.connect();
     //var json = '';
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where email = '+req.params.email, function (error, rows, fields) { 
         str='';
         for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        str = str + rows[i].email +'\n';
//       res.end( str);
            res.end( str);
          //  json = JSON.stringify(rows); //displaying json file
        //res.send(json);
      });
   connection.end(); 
});
```

And in my home.html i have a text box and a button that represents a search action to do that retrieves data from the database :

```
<div class="search" id = "page_content1">
      <h1>Enter Candidate's email: </h1>
      </br>
      <form method="get" action="http://127.0.0.1:1212/getallusers/email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="search" id = "search" onclick="display()"/>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Now I want to have the results retrieved by the query in app.js file to be displayed in my home.html file,any help on how to do that?

Comment: If you want to do this server-side, you'll need to use a templating engine, e.g. [jade](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jade); If you're used to PHP, you may want to check out [ejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ejs)

Comment: Okay could you give me a reference or an example on how to use jade?